# InterfaceError: Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, web-scraping

An app that takes from Truecar the price and functionality of the first 20 people who sell a custom machine (the name of the machine is given at the input) and stores it in a custom database.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode


def req(carname):
   try:
       URL = 'https://www.truecar.com/used-cars-for-sale/listings/' + carname + '/?sort[]=best_match'
       req = requests.get(URL)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
       car_name = soup.find_all(class_='vehicle-header-make-model text-truncate')
       car_price = soup.find_all(class_='heading-3 margin-y-1 font-weight-bold')
       car_km = soup.find_all('div', {'data-test': 'vehicleMileage'})

       car_name_list = []
       for i in car_name:
           car_name_list.append(i.get_text())
       # print(car_name_list)
       car_price_list = []
       for i in car_price:
           car_price_list.append(i.get_text())
       # print(car_price_list)
       car_km_list = []
       for i in car_km:
           car_km_list.append(i.get_text())
       # print(car_km_list)
       return car_name_list, car_price_list, car_km_list
   except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
       raise SystemExit(err)

print('ok1')



def Insert_data():
   print('->')
   cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='tool', password='',
                             host='127.0.0.1',
                            database='learn')
   cursor = cnx.cursor()
   query = ('INSERT INTO cars (Car_Name,Car_price,Car_km) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)')
   i = showdata()
   insert_rows = (i[0], i[1], i[2])
   #Car_Name = i[0]
   #Car_price = i[1]
   #Car_km = [2]
   #insert_rows = (Car_Name, Car_price, Car_km)
   for row in insert_rows:
       print('ok2')
       cursor.executemany(query, insert_rows)
   print('Data Inserted')
   cnx.commit()

   Sql_comment =('SELECT * FROM cars')
   cursor.execute(Sql_comment)
   result = list(cursor.fetchall())
   print(result)

   cursor.close()
   cnx.close()

def showdata():
   data_ = req('acura')
   # for i in data_:
   #     print(i,'\n')
   # print(data_)
   # print(data_[1])
   # print(data_[0],data_[1],data_[2])
   # car_data=dict(zip(data_[0],zip(data_[1],data_[2])))
   # list_car_data=list(car_data.items())
   # print(car_data)
   # print(list_car_data)
   return data_


req('acura')
Insert_data()
showdata()
```

my problem is in insert_rows, I tried to solve them but I can't

error:  Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters

thanks
.
.

Comment: Maybe the type of parameters you submit is not the same as the type of corresponding fields.